# "Removes her dress" versus "strips her dress" versus "sheds her dress"

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct?

> She **removes** her dress and dives in the pool in her underwear.
>   She **strips** her dress and dives in the pool in her underwear.
>   She **sheds** her dress and dives in the pool in her underwear.

Comment: She *strips* or *strips herself*; she *strips off* her dress. And she dives *into* the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are grammatical, but sentence 2 is not idiomatic English in this context.

Sentences 1 and 3 are semantically fine and probably considered acceptable usage, but I'd write them this way:

> She {**removes** [*my preferred verb*] / sheds} her dress and dives **into** the pool in her underwear.

Comment: even the following sentence it should be  "into" ? I'm not getting why it should be "into".  "Dive in the pool" - seems fine.  "She stripes down to her underwear and dives in the pool."

Comment: @T2E: It's a style preference based on the semantics of _in_ versus _into_. What most people mean by "She dives in the pool_ is that she's not in the pool but on the side of the pool or o the diving board, and then she launches herself head-first **into** the swimming pool. If I'm _in the pool_, then I can _pee **in** the pool_ because that's where I am. If I'm standing next to the pool, then I can _pee **into** the pool"_ because that's where my urine stream is going. _In the pool_ means _surrounded by the water contained in the pool_. Semantic problem: comes from _Dive in!_ not _Dive into!_

Comment: @Bill: [Good call](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dive+into+the+pool%2C+dive+in+the+pool&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). By the way, your example reminds me of the old sign: WELCOME TO OUR OOL. (And then the subtext: _Notice there is no ‘P’ in it. Please help keep it that way_.)

Comment: @user264 Dive INTO the pool would mean you did a headfirst dive from outside the pool into it.  This is the more idiomatic usage.  Someone would probably say "dive in the pool" when discussing something like training for SCUBA diving.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the second sentence, I would use "She strips down to her underwear and dives into the pool."

*Shed* means "to let something fall; to drop something" and it can be used in your sentence, in the same way it is used in the following one.

> Luke shed his clothes onto the floor.

Also *remove* can be used, as one of its meanings is "to take off clothing from the body."

Answer (score 0):

> She removes her dress and dives in[to] the pool in her underwear.

This has a fairly formal, non-salacious air to it. It's the way a paper like *The New York Times* would write up the event. "Disrobe" is another word that could be used here.

> She strips [off] her dress and dives in[to] the pool in her underwear.

This is a bit more salacious, possibly implying that she is a bit "loose" or even "slutty". Without more context (e.g., *The flaming petrol covered her. She stripped off...*), it's difficult to tell for sure what the intent of the author is. To "strip" off clothing is usually used when sex is the next step, but not always. It's done in a hurry without the bother of folding or putting it away.

> She sheds her dress and dives in[to] the pool in her underwear.

Again, to "shed" clothing implies that sexual activity may be nigh, almost as much as to "strip" does. Clothing is being removed rapidly and dropped just anywhere, rather than being neatly put away.